# How do I show an image in main stage after calling push()?

Tags: galleria

I am trying to use Galleria where I am dynamically inserting images by calling the push() API. That part is working just great when it comes to pushing a new image in the carousel. However, what I want to do is as soon as I push a new image, I would like to load that image in the main stage to display the large version. I can't figure out how to do that and am hoping someone here can help.

Here is what I have tried so far. I thought after pushing a new image I can call the getDataLength(). This would potentially return either original length or (original length + 1) if it accounted for the new pushed image. getDataLength() returns the original length. So I tried to use show(original length + 1) hoping that would load the new image. However, this simply revolves around and shows the first image in the carousel instead of loading the last newly pushed image.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.